# MVC5 Application out of the box Jquery Error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I installed Visual Studio Express 2013 and created a new MVC5 project.

To create my project I did 
"New Project"
"ASP.NET Web Application" (named my project here)
And then Selected "MVC"

I then ran the project through Visual Studio.  Everything worked fine at first.  All of the links work.  When you pull up the register screen, it displays fine, but when you click in any of the text boxes, the following jquery error occurs:

**Unhandled exception at line 1248, column 5 in scripts/jquery.validate.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference**

I expected this to work out of the box.  All I installed was Visual Studio Express 2013.  Is there something else I needed to install?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out the answer myself.  I thought I would post, just in case someone else has the same problem.

When you create the project, you need to have .NET 4.5 selected and not .NET 4.5.1

This fixed the issue for me.